# Discord: can't extract the html and style of a message

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to get an `.html` file with the html code of a Discord message and its styles (.css), so that when I open that `.html` in browser it looks the way it looks in Discord:

[image]

I tried using this code

```
var el = document.querySelector('#chat-messages-123456');
var els = el.getElementsByTagName("*");

for(var i = -1, l = els.length; ++i < l;){
    els[i].setAttribute("style", window.getComputedStyle(els[i]).cssText);
}
```

but it doesn't work: the resulting `div` that I copy doesn't contain most of the styles.

I also tried looking at Computed CSS in element inspector, but it didn't even show `background-color:` property.

Comment: That's likely because the background color is transparent. Many of the CSS styles are no doubt applied to the parent elements. Many properties in CSS are non-inherited, meaning they are not based on the computed value of their parents. `background-x` is one of these non-inherited properties, as opposed to one like `font-x` which is inherited.

Comment: Also, that's gotta be one of the strangest for loop declarations I've ever seen. Initializing to -1 to then use a pre-increment for the condition (and then not have a final statement) is super strange to me. Not that it's wrong or anything. It's just really interesting to me.